# HTML Agility pack with c#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

c# code:`

```
var node = new HtmlWeb();

                var doc = node.Load("http://ask.fm/");

                HtmlNode ournode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='heads']")

                textBox1.Text=ournode.InnerHtml;
```

`
html code :

```
//< div id="heads" >

      <a href="/sudenur3434" data-rlt-aid="welcome_head"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_30132803" src="http://img3.ask.fm/assets2/103/548/655/872/thumb_tiny/IMG_20150513_192250.jpg" /></a>

      <a href="/leylaulucay" data-rlt-aid="welcome_head"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_56578735" src="http://img1.ask.fm/assets2/091/364/883/712/thumb_tiny/11094711_919135961470973_149663457_njpg720960png1280963.png" /></a>
```

I want to see the following in the text box

/sudenur3434

/leylaulucay

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx and here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acf0435b-07fd-4063-b1ab-b52312cf28f0/find-href-in-html-with-html-agility-pack?forum=Vsexpressvcs

Answer (score 0):

I have added an additional line to your code:

```
var node = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = node.Load("http://ask.fm/");
HtmlNode ournode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='heads']")

var val = ournode.Attributes["href"].Value;

textBox1.Text=val;
```

This would let you get the href attribute. Simply use the same code to get the other nodes href value and then add them to your textbox

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe

Comment: Can you tell me the inner message? I am assuming that the rest of your code works

Comment: "check to determine if the object is null before calling the method."

Comment: How do I get the text in the href?

Comment: Look at the links in my first comment. That's got all you need.

Comment: @LocEngineer Didn't even see the div as it was outside the code block in the Q.. My bad

Comment: I do not understand. are you coding please :(

Answer (score 0):

Since a text **box** is usually used for one liners, I am giving you an example that will simply write all links in the direct output window of VS.

If you use e.g. a ListBox instead of a text box you can replace Debug.Print by e.g. `ListBox1.Items.Add(href.Value)`

This here will give you all href urls from all a children in div id="heads":

```
var site = new HtmlWeb();
var htmldoc = site.Load("http://ask.fm/");

var headDiv = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='heads']");
if (headDiv != null)
{
    var anchors = headDiv.SelectNodes("a");
    foreach (HtmlNode aNode in anchors)
    {
        var href = aNode.Attributes.AttributesWithName("href").FirstOrDefault();
        if (href != null)
            Debug.Print(href.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the "heads" href's.

Comment: Would you please start asking questions and responding/commenting with a little more than just "I want"?
If you want detailed reposnes you need to give detailed information. The code above will give you the hrefs of the "heads" division. If that is not what you want then what exactly is?

Comment: listbox items:
/
javascript:void(0)
/signup
javascript:void(0)
javascript:void(0)
javascript:void(0)
javascript:void(0)
/remind/request
/sudenur3434(example)
/leylaulucay(example)

ı want to ..:


/sudenur3434(example)
/leylaulucay(example)

Comment: I see; there was a slight error in the code above. SelectNodes("//a") included anchors from outside the desired scope. I have correct that to  SelectNodes("a"). Should provide correct output now.

Answer (score -1):

```
< div id="heads" >

  <a href="/sudenur3434" data-rlt-aid="welcome_head"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_30132803" src="http://img3.ask.fm/assets2/103/548/655/872/thumb_tiny/IMG_20150513_192250.jpg" /></a>

  <a href="/leylaulucay" data-rlt-aid="welcome_head"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_5
```

how to agility pack parse in textbox